# react-native-navigation combining createStackNavigator, BottomTabNavigator and Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I currently have a navigation structure that looks like this:

- Newsfeed (in RootBottomTabNavigator)

  - NewsfeedItem
  - CommentModal
- Search (in RootBottomTabNavigator)

```
const NewsfeedStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Newsfeed: {
      screen: NewsfeedScreen,
    },
    NewsfeedItem: {
      screen: NewsfeedItemScreen,
    },
  }
);

const NewsfeedItemStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: NewsfeedStack,
    },
    CommentModal: {
      screen: CommentModal,
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: { screen: SearchScreen }
  }
)

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Newsfeed: { screen: NewsfeedStack },
        Search: { screen: SearchStack },
    },
);
```

Two issues I could not resolve with this set up are:

1. Hiding the BottomTabs on the NewsfeedItem and CommentModal screens.
2. Clicking on the tab to return to the initial screen no longer works because the navigation stack thinks that the NewsfeedItem is the initial screen.

Is there a setup to fix these issues?